# Using Frame Buffer Objects (FBO) in Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: buffer, frame, c++builder, fbo, borland-c++

I have an "access violation" on the Frame Buffer Object (FBO)'s command glGenFramebuffersEXT :

```
    void TGLForm::DrawScene()
    {
    wglMakeCurrent(ghDC, ghRC);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLuint framebuffer, texturefbo;
    GLenum status;

    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &framebuffer);  // access violation here
```

Founding a help thread concerning the FBOs, I checked that the glext.h initialization were okay and repeated amidst the preprocessor lines this way :

```
    #include "glext.h"
    #include "wglext.h"

    extern PFNGLGENFRAMEBUFFERSEXTPROC glGenFramebuffersEXT = (PFNGLGENFRAMEBUFFERSEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenFramebuffersEXT");
    extern PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC glBindFramebufferEXT = (PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindFramebufferEXT");
    extern PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE2DEXTPROC glFramebufferTexture2DEXT = (PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE2DEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glFramebufferTexture2DEXT");
    extern PFNGLCHECKFRAMEBUFFERSTATUSEXTPROC glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT = (PFNGLCHECKFRAMEBUFFERSTATUSEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT");
    extern PFNGLGENRENDERBUFFERSEXTPROC glGenRenderbuffersEXT = (PFNGLGENRENDERBUFFERSEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenRenderbuffersEXT");
    extern PFNGLBINDRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC glBindRenderbufferEXT = (PFNGLBINDRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindRenderbufferEXT");
    extern PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEEXTPROC glRenderbufferStorageEXT = (PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glRenderbufferStorageEXT");
    extern PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT = (PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT");
```

=> The access violation remains.

Another help thread induced me to download the NVIDIA OpenGL SDK's because I have a GT9800 Nvidia card : it didn't remove the "access violation".

I tried using GLee and Glew in Borland Builder 6 :

- to include Glew in Borland it is first needed to convert Visual Studio "coff" lib from coff to borland builder "omf" lib,
- but with the borland command script "coff2omf.exe" I get this error label : "invalid machine type" - and with "objconv.exe" I get this error : "import library cannot convert to static library".

=> does someone know how I may manage to convert the Glew "coff" lib to the Borland Builder format "omf" successfully ?

=> how can we convert an "import library" to a "static library" ?

Comment: So when I try to include Glee.h, it needs to have glext.h called before.
And glext.h needs gl.h called before.
But Glee.h does not support gl.h being called before !!! ???

#include "windows.h"
#include "glxext.h"
#include "GLee.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include "glext.h"
#include "wglext.h"

Comment: Note that GLEW works just fine by adding the source files to your project. No need to convert any library. Read "Including the source files" at: http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html  (note that you should probably not try to load extensions manually if you're a beginner to OpenGL, it is painful and error prone, GLEW is plug-and-play)

Comment: Ok thanks I have eventually copied glew's dll and lib files in the right directories, and including glew succeeds, but I have not tried again FBO. I will tell if it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. download and use GLEW *.h,*.c source code

   ```
   #define GLEW_STATIC
   #include "gl\glew.c"  // ~900KB file !!!
   ```

   - I am using it for many years inside borland source without any problems
   - if you have problems with include path then just use relative paths
2. do not forget to init glew first

   ```
   glewInit();
   ```

   - of course your OpenGL must be initialized prior to this !!!
3. check if you have FBO support

   ```
   if (glGenFramebuffersEXT==NULL) error ...
   ```
4. FBO usage

   - if all is OK
   - then you still can have access violations !!!
   - if FBO not used properly ...
   - but this is not your case yet ...