# Render a unique video stream in two separate opengl windows

Tags: c++, opengl, c++builder

I rendered this video stream in one opengl window (called by the Main window (UnitMainForm.cpp: I am using Borland Builder C++ 6.0)).

In this first openGL window, there is a timer on which timer a boolean "lmutex" is switched and a "DrawScene" function is called followed by a "Yield" function.

In this "DrawScene" function, the video stream frames are drawn by a function called "paintgl".

How can I render this video stream in another borland builder window, preferably with the use of pixel buffers?

This second borland builder is intended to be a preview window, so it can be of a smaller size (mipmap?) and with a slower timer (or the same size, same timer, it's ok too).

Here are the results I had with different techniques:

- with pixel buffers, I achieved (all in the DrawScene function) to write the paintgl on a backbuffer and with wglShareLists to render this backbuffer to a texture mapped to a quad; but I can't manage to use this texture in another window, wglShareLists works in the first window but fails in the second window when I try to share the objects of the back_buffer with the new window RC (pixel format problem ?) (C++ problem perhaps? How to keep the buffer without it being released, and render it on a quad in a different DC (or same RC ?):

[Access violation on wglBindTexImageARB ; due to WGL_FRONT_LEFT_ARB not defined allthoug wglext.h included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741994/access-violation-on-wglbindteximagearb-due-to-wgl-front-left-arb-not-defined-al)

[wglShareLists fails with error 6 : ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE The handle is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720776/wglsharelists-fails-with-error-6-error-invalid-handle-the-handle-is-invalid)

- with calling two objects of the same class (the opengl window): I see one time on three times the two video streams correctly rendered; but one time on three times there is a constant flicker on one or both window, and one time on three one or the other window is constantly blank or constantly black; perhaps should I synchronize the timers or is there a way to have no flicker? but this solution seems to me sketchy: the video stream sometimes slows on one of the two windows, I think it heavy to call twice the capture video stream.
- I tried to use FBO, with GLew, or with wgl functions but I got stuck on access violations on glGenFrameBuffer; perhaps Borland 6 (2002) is perhaps too old to support FBO (~2004 ?); I updated my really recent NVIDIA card (9800GT) drivers and downloaded the nvidia opengl SDK (which is just an exe file : strange) :

[Using Frame Buffer Objects (FBO) in Borland C++ Builder 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714247/using-frame-buffer-objects-fbo-in-borland-c-builder-6)

Is there a C++ program canvas, or pieces of code which would clarify how I can display in a second window the video I perfectly display in one window?

Comment: Up for help : I just need to strictly duplicate one OpenGL window. Any advice, hint or help are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First of, all the left and right draw buffers are not meant to be used for rendering to two different render contexts, but to allow for stereoscopic rendering in one render context being signalled to some 3D hardware (e.g. shutter glasses) by the driver. Apart from that does your graphics hardware/driver not support that extension - the identifiers being defined in glew or not.

What you want to do is to render your video frames to a VBO and share that VBO with two render contexts. Basically a VBO is just a texture that you can use both as render target (render buffer) or render source (texture).

There are numerous VBO examples out there, most coded in C though. If you can read German, you may however want to check DelphiGL.com; the people there have very good OpenGL knowledge and quite a useful Wiki with docs, examples and tutorials.